# The differences between a=1, b=2 and a=1 (newline) b=2 in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby. I just noticed that if I wrote

```
a = 1, b = 2
puts a, b
```

Then the output is

```
1
2
2
```

But if I wrote

```
a = 1
b = 2
```

Then the output turns out to be

```
1
2
```

Why?
And I have the following code:

```
s = 0, i = 1

while i <= 100
    s += i
    i++
end

puts s,i
```

When I runs it, it has the following errors:

```
test.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
test.rb:16: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting     keyword_end
puts s, i
         ^
```

I also don't know where I'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: If you have two questions, please ask two questions. As it turns out, both of the questions you asked have already been asked and answered many, many, many, many, many times on StackOverflow, but it is impossible to point out a duplicate, because you munged two questions into one.

Comment: Sorry but I searched carefully before I asked and I didn't find the answer I need. Next time I'll split my question up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to assign both `a` and `b` on one line, pick one of these syntaxes:

```
a, b = 1, 2
```

or

```
a = 1; b = 2
```

Either of those should work.

But if you write `a = 1, b = 2`, Ruby interprets it as:

```
a = [1, b = 2]
```

You could have seen that `a` is an array for yourself by running `puts a.inspect` or `p a` for short.

Your last code block does not work because `i++` is not valid syntax in Ruby.  Try `i += 1`.

Comment: Thanks! I really didn't figure out the inaccessibility of i++ in ruby! 

Comment: Good explanation, but you could improve it by explaining *why* Ruby interprets `a=1,b=2` (or just `a=1,2`) as it does. As you know the reason is related to parallel assignment. There's a good explanation of the case where there are fewer lvalues than rvalues [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/the-ruby-programming/9780596516178/ch04s05.html). One thing I just learned is that you can write `a, = 1,2`, in which case `a #=> 1`. (I've always written `a,_ = 1,2`.)

Answer (score 3):

**Answer to you first question:**

Look at it this way:

```
a = 1, b = 2
puts a.inspect, b.inspect
# [1, 2]
# 2
```

`a` becomes an array of values `1` and `2` when you do it this way:

```
a = 1, b = 2
```

Because, it is interpreted this way:

```
First, 2 is assigned to b i.e. b = 2
Then, (1,  b = 2) is assinged to a i.e. a = [1, 2]
```

P.S. [inspect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-inspect) is a great way to observe what's inside an object as it returns a string containing a human-readable representation of the object.

**Answer to you second  question:**

There are 2 problems in the code block:

First, `s = 0, i = 1` is wrong again! (as explained in the first part) You have to do it either:

```
s = 0 ; i = 1
```

or:

```
s = 0
i = 1
```

way to assign values to `s` and `i`.

Second, there is no `++` operator in Ruby, so you have to do: `i += 1` instead of `i++`.

Here is the correct version of your last code block which works:

```
s = 0
i = 1

while i <= 100
   s += i
   i += 1
end

puts s, i
```

Comment: Sorry I just adopted another answer :( Thx anyway!

Answer (score 1):

```
2.1.6 :001 > a=1, b=2
 => [1, 2] 
2.1.6 :002 > puts a,b
1
2
2
 => nil 
2.1.6 :003 > a
 => [1, 2] 
2.1.6 :004 > b
 => 2 
2.1.6 :005 >
```

You can clearly see that `a= [1,2]` and `b=2` so the output is

```
puts a,b
1
2
2
```

Answer (score 0):

you have two write as

```
    a,b=1,2

    puts a,b
```

If you have write as

```
  a=1,b=2

 Then value of a=[1,2] and value of b=2

 when you puts a,b then output will be as

 1

 2

 2
```

And your while loop will be as

```
 s=0

 i=1

 While (i <100)

     s=s+1

     i = i + 1

 end

   puts s,i
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a coma to separate values you are actually declaring an Array.

> a = 1, b = 2

is

> a = [1, b]

and because b = 2

> a = [1, 2]

So you are printing the array first and the variable b

Use a = 1; b = 2 instead if you want to use a single line.

you can launch IRB to play with those things...

i++ is not a Ruby syntax. Use i += 1

Comment: yeah ruby here is not the same as c++